# Is it possible to print a statement to the user when a list index out of range

Tags: python, python-docx

I am working on some code (as shown below) to extract the footer and header from a Word document. I am using python 3.10.4 and the python-docx library (version 0.8.1.1) on PyCharm (Community Edition 2021.3.3). Only the footer and header from the second section is extracted. This works as long as the document has two sections (created via 1x Section Break (Next Page) ).

If a document that does not have a minimum of two sections is accessed by the code, an error message is displayed by the console. This message is as follows: IndexError: list index out of range. This is as expected as the document does not have the required number of sections for the code to execute properly.

I would like to know if it is possible to print a message (e.g. "Doc has less than 2 sections") to the user in the instance that the document causes such an error. I have tried to use the `len` function to check if the variable "section2" is empty and if it is print a statement about the wrong number of sections in the doc. But this approach produces the following error message: TypeError: object of type 'Section' has no len().

Any form of help would be appreciated. If there are any questions about the code, please ask.

```
from docx import Document

# obtain file name from user
filename = input("Enter file name (e.g. my_file.docx): ")
print()
# access Word document file
WordFile = Document(filename)

# access the 2nd section
# [1] refers to the second section of the Word doc
section2 = WordFile.sections[1]

# loop through the 2nd section and print the header
header2 = section2.header
section2header = sorted(set())
for paragraph in header2.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        # check for duplicates and append unique values to the sorted list section2header
        if paragraph.text not in section2header:
            section2header.append(paragraph.text)
print("Section 2 Header:", section2header)

# loop through the 2nd section and print the footer
footer2 = section2.footer
section2footer = sorted(set())
for paragraph in footer2.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        # check for duplicates and append unique values to the sorted list section2footer
        if paragraph.text not in section2footer:
            section2footer.append(paragraph.text)
print("Section 2 Footer:", section2footer)
```

Comment: Use `try - except`?

Comment: You can write *len(WordFile.sections)*. Also, what do you think *sorted(set())* will give you other than an empty list?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a `try-except` block is what you desire? ([link to try-except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)) Then, once the error occurs (out of range), the `except` block is triggered, in this case, it prints an error message to the user. For example:

```
try:
    # any bit of code that causes the out of range error
except:
    print("Hey user, an error occured!")
```

The `except` block should catch when the error occurs and then execute the code in its body.

If you'd like it to catch just your specific error, try this:

```
try:
    # any bit of code that causes the out of range error
except IndexError as error:
    print("Hey user, an error occured!")
```

Comment: _The `except` block catch when..._. Bro, The `except`  block catch every error you need to use `except IndexError`.

Comment: I suspected they'd want to simply catch everything, I've now added both cases, thanks. @SharimIqbal

Comment: He says index out of range in title

Comment: So I have tried the following code:
 `try:
   # any bit of code that causes the out of range error
    section2 == WordFile.section[0]
except IndexError as error:
    print("Hey user, an error occured!")`

But the code still displays an error message.

Comment: Perhaps another type of error is occurring, try just a general try-except

Comment: I think I have a temporary solution:
`# check if the number of sections in the doc is less than 2
if len(WordFile.sections) < 2:
    print("Wrong number of sections in document")`

The code still shows the error message, but at least the user will know why the error occurred. Would be nice to prevent the error message from showing, and just show a print statement ("Wrong number of sections in document")

Comment: Here is the whole error message being displayed:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the\python\file\directory", line 23, in <module>
    section2 = WordFile.sections[1]  # access the 2nd section
  File "the\python\file\folder\directory\venv\lib\site-packages\docx\section.py", line 30, in __getitem__
    return Section(self._document_elm.sectPr_lst[key], self._document_part)
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you tried to use `len(section2)`, but in order to get the number of sections you should be able to use `len(WordFile.sections)`.

If in `section2 = WordFile.sections[1]` there is no second section, the `section2` will not be "empty", but it won't exist at all.